# C++ call function with reference to array of const integers

Tags: c++, pass-by-reference

Lets say i have these two function definitions:

```
int* first(int const (& array)[], int const size);
void second(int const array[], int const size);
```

and at the implementation of second i want to make a call to first like this:

```
void second(int const array[], int const size)
{
    int* something = first(*array, size);
}
```

Thats when the compiler tells me: "no matching function for call to 'first'". What is the correct way to call first from second in this case?

Comment: The first one shouldn't even compile. Have you tried it?

Comment: Whooops... sorry. My IDE didn't show any error though. Should i use a constant pointer in this case?

Comment: No, the array needs a size: `int const (& array)[42]`

Comment: Yes.  The const pointer is in this case an excellent alternative, givent the fact that size is variable as the second arguement suggests

Comment: @Christophe That's right. I'll do it that way. Thanks guys.

Comment: I mean the array needs a size for your question to even make sense.

Answer (score 0):

If you really have to use arrays, I would suggest using `std::array`:

```
#include <array>

template<size_t N>
int first(std::array<int, N> const& array) ;

template<size_t N>
void second(std::array<int, N> const& array)
{
    int something = first(array);
}

int main()
{
   std::array<int, 3> a = {1,2,3};

   second(a);
}
```

If you have a array with dynamic size, free yourself from the burden of manually managing the array and use `std::vector` instead.